# Определение является ли раздел реестра ссылкой

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, реестр

Необходимо определить с помощью winapi, является ли заданный раздел реестра ссылкой на другой. Например, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\SAM` дублирует `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM`.

Пытался решить вопрос следующим образом, передавая различный путь к ветке, но все попытки не увенчались успехом:

```
HKEY hKey;
LONG ret = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                        L"SECURITY", 0, 
                        KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_READ, &hKey);
DWORD regType;
DWORD flags = RRF_RT_ANY;
ret = RegGetValue(hKey, NULL, L"SAM", flags, &regType, NULL, NULL);
if (regType == REG_LINK)
{
    // do cool stuff
}
```

Вопрос: возможно ли получить данную информацию указанным способом. Если да, то как правильно передавать название (код возврата в основном 2 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND и 87 - ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER). Если данным способом невозможно получить информацию, о том, является ли раздел ссылкой, буду благодарен за другие решения

Comment: Функция RegGetValue используется для значений, а вы пытаетесь применить ее к ключу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за внимание. Получил ответ на забугорном форуме:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009194/checking-if-registry-key-is-link-to-or-copy-of-another-one/53010756